Definition of the Conformal algebra generators
In the textbook "Introduction to Conformal Field Theory" by Blumenhagen and Plauschinn (2009), Section 2.1, the generators of the Lie algebra corresponding to the conformal group for the Euclidean $d$-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^{d,0}$ with $d\geq 3$ are defined in a confusing fashion. They are given in terms of the generators $D,P,K,L,$ populating a $(d+2)\times (d+2)$ matrix, but the portions of this matrix seems to be overlapping. For instance, the row $J_{0,\mu}$, defined as $\frac{1}{2}(P_\mu +K_\mu)$ should be also the first row of the minor $J_{\mu, \nu}$  (defined to be the $L_{\mu, \nu}$) - assuming the indices $\mu, \nu$ run from 0 to $d-1$. Also $J_{-1,0}=D$ overlaps with $J_{-1,\mu}$  for $\mu=0$, set to be $\frac{1}{2}(P_\mu -K_\mu)$ ...
On other hand, the operators $J_{n,-1}$ are not defined at all.
Is there a typo somewhere or I don`t understand something?
I saw these exact definitions in other places, but they all seem to be copy-paste from one to another.
Any clarifications would be appreciated.
Snapshots:



I think Greek labels run over $1,2,\ldots, d-1$. So there is no "overlap". Moreover the tensor $J_{m,n}$ should be antisymmetric, which covers for the undefined entries.

Thanks, @Icv. This doesn't seem right, as the rotation operator $L$ should act on the d-dimensional space, so it's indices should run $0$ to $d-1$ or $1$ to $d$. About the undefined entries you are probably correct.

The Greek indices run from $1$ to $d$ and the size of the matrix is $(d + 2) \times (d + 2)$.

@ConnorBehan I agree, this also gives the correct number of generators $N$. But I'm perplexed by Eq. (2.9), shouldn't the labels run from $-1$ to $d$ then?

It is an error currently not listed in the errata. The sentence above eq. (2.9) should read:

One can then verify that $J_{m,n}$ with $m, n = −1, 0, 1, \dots , \color{red}{d}$ satisfy the following commutation relations $\dots$

References:

R. Blumenhagen and E. Plauschinn, Intro to CFT, Lecture Notes in Physics 779, 2009; sentence above eq. (2.9). Errata.


Thank you very much!
